# API Requests - Creating dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, api, request

I am using the below code to request some data from the iTunes API.Once I have the "Response" object I extract its contents with the "text" method and then I use "loads" function to create a list/dictionary. I can do the same thing with i_Tunes_response.json().Is there any particular difference between the two methods of creating the dictionary?Is there a best practice?I am not trying to achieve anything, just experimenting with APIs.

```
import requests

import json

parameters={"term":"parameter1","entity":"parameter2"}

i_Tunes_response=requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search",params=parameters)
print(type(i_Tunes_response))
text=i_Tunes_response.text
print(type(text))

x=i_Tunes_response.json()
y=json.loads(text)

print(type(x))
print(type(y))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you're better off using `response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/?highlight=.text#requests.Response.text), `response.text` returns content of the response, in unicode.

If you use `response.json(**kwargs)` it returns json-encoded content of the response. With `.json(**kwargs)` you can use keyword arguments that are passed to `json.loads()`.